# Any way to make AR.js camera less sensitive to movement?

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit, ar.js, jsartoolkit

After testing with default and custom marker/model of various size and distance, I concluded that the reason my AR models are having seizure (jittering/flickering/shaking like mad) is because of my hand movement. When the (phone) camera is at rest, the model is stable when the camera is stable.

Because the intention is to share the end product with the public (or anyone whose phone supports WebRTC), I can't calibrate the AR camera, because that would only fix my (phone) problem, not the other audience's.

Is there a setting in AR.js or ARToolkit that governs the sensitivity of the camera?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are facing hard mad movements/hyper-sensitivity shaking of images with Ar.JS, and you are using multiple markers in the same page, the solution is to add a `<a-entity camera></entity>` inside the `<a-scene>` that contains the markers.

This avoids the automatic camera(s) created by a-frame, and makes everything more stable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the object position and orientation from AR.js and average that over a few frames to smooth things out.

Comment: A Github issue for AR.js about this with some code I found in another SO answer: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/467